# PHP7 and IIS8 HTTP Error 500.0 - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Tags: c++, windows-server-2012, iis-8, php-7

On Windows Server 2012, I'm running IIS 8 and PHP 7.04.  I'm getting the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>   C:\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

When I run the following from command line:

> c:\php\php.exe phpinfo()

I get the following error:

> The program can't start because VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing from your computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fox this problem.

I have installed the Visual C++ redistributable 2015 from MS (vc_redist.x64.exe).  It looks like VCRUNTIME140.dll is put in C:\Windows\System32.

Am I missing a PHP path or environment var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to install 32 bit version of Visual C++ redistributable 2015 (VC_redist.x86.exe).  Thanks for the tip from here: 
https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/482